# Should I tell applicants they have not been selected for a position, if the application process was long ago?

Tags: communication, applications

Our team advertised some internship positions last December, and we got dozens of applications for each. We made a shortlist, interviewed those on the shortlist, picked our candidates and wrote polite rejections to those we had interviewed but not selected. The internships were for a duration of three months.

However, the vast majority of applicants was not on the shortlist and never heard anything back. Since it is now more than nine months since they applied, I seriously doubt anyone would still be expecting a positive reply.

Should I tell them anyway, to give a sense of closure, or would that rather be an unpleasant reminder of something that had not worked out?

Edit: Thank you for all your replies! Two short clarifications: 1. We did inform those we had shortlisted and interviewed. The question is about applicants we didn't have interviews or other contact with. 2. The CVs we get are pre-filtered by HR, and HR does not notify those it filters out, so in a way, it could be considered company policy. My only choice is whether to personally reach out to those whose CVs I've seen but decided not to shortlist.

Comment: They probably remember your company - they have you on the list of "never bothered to reply" so when they see your next advert you might miss out on the good ones. I remember talking to colleagues about the replies we did and did not receive from companies...

Comment: It’s probably a waste of your time. Anyone looking for a job more than 200 days ago likely moved onto their other choice.  In the future you probably shouldn’t be one of those companies that never inform potential candidates that they were not selected. As somebody who was never notified of a decision before, I not only would blacklist your company, I would spread my experiences to anyone in my circle.

Comment: In my experience, there's no reason to notify *everyone* that *applied* that didn't get the job. That would be a waste of time. Having said that... if they got on the shortlist and were contacted, I would expect you to notify them once you've decided not to proceed with them.

Comment: @JeffC - It's just common curiosity to tell an applicant they didn't get the job after 14 days.

Comment: @Donald I think you mean "courtesy", not "curiosity". I've been on both sides and never experienced this (notifying *every applicant* after 14 days whether they were interviewed or not) in the US working for a couple handfuls of companies over the last 30 years.

Comment: As someone that has deep experience with the "resume black hole", PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE tell people that apply that they are no longer under consideration.

Comment: @JeffC it does not take alot of time to have a pre-written email sent out to X number of emails bcc-d. It shows respect towards humans to not to have their prepared application disappear in a blackhole.

Comment: I have had 2 companies get back to me 6+ months later showing interest (one of which did it twice and no showed for one of the phone interviews).  They had new positions open and my resume on file.  Of course by then I had made other commitments.  I rarely received feedback for applications that never made it to an interview, so this is not uncommon.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't tell them in the way it was done in this classic [Monty Python sketch](https://youtu.be/D4iFzweRf3E?t=263) (start video over to see how it leads up to this point)

Comment: @aqua I agree, all that takes is a MTA, correct SMTP-settings and a mail-client - 100's of applicants could be notified in seconds (or minutes in case someone doesn't have a predefined text snippet). One could even automate it by spawning a cron-job that propagates a predefined mail-body via node-mailer at a certain point in time and pass a list of receipients to that small node-application.. ;)

Comment: @JeffC There will likely be more time wasted in case of not sending a reply, than in case of sending a reply. Sending a negative reply takes only a few instant; if you have lots of candidates, you can send all the negative replies in one block. However, if you don't inform a candidate that you're not interested in their application, they will remain in the unknown and possibly keep contacting you to get an answer. You end up wasting their time and your own just because you couldn't have the courtesy of sending one email to inform them in the first place.

Answer (score 129):

At this point far too much time has passed. If you've ignored a candidate for nine months, there's no question in their minds that you've rejected them. Half of them have probably even forgotten who you are or what they applied for.

If anything it makes your company look incompetent that you're only responding to them nine months after the fact - because either it means you forgot to get back to them, or that you've taken nine months to come to a decision.

In future, when you decide not to proceed with a candidate, it would be courteous to inform them.

Comment: I just got an email last month from a company I interviewed for in February telling me they're going a different direction.  In this case it was "only" 4 months, not 9 but everything you said was 100% true for me.  I already got the message long ago that they weren't going to make me an offer.  Additionally, I thought they looked really dumb for sending the email after that much time passed.

Comment: "If anything it makes your company look _even more_ incompetent that you're only responding to them nine months after the fact" <-- Fixed that for ya. Since I'm in the middle of a job search right now, there's nothing more annoying than hearing _nothing_ back from an employer or recruiter. (Especially from a recruiter that has contacted _me_, not one where I made the initial contact.)

Comment: @FreeMan That's why a lot of companies have "if you don't hear anything from us, assume you've not made the cut" language in their communications. Some companies even put a time limit on it, as in "if you haven't heard from us in X weeks, we've decided to not proceed further with your application".

Answer (score 33):

As a rough guideline, from their last interview (or the last time you had contact with them):

**Less than 1 week** is the ideal time-frame to notify a candidate of rejection (but not a time-frame too many companies achieve).

**Between 1 week and 1 month** is getting a bit slow, but this is still a common time-frame for companies and you could expect most candidates to still be waiting for an answer.

**Between 1 and 2 months** would be pushing it. I wouldn't expect many candidates to still be waiting, but I would still suggest sending a notification, as many will probably appreciate it.

**More than 2 months** is generally too much, and you should probably just leave it. Some candidates may still appreciate a notification, but basically no-one would still be waiting for an answer and beyond that a decent number of candidates will start forgetting that they even applied. After too long candidates will start wondering what sorts of problems there are at your company that would cause such a delayed response (which could dissuade them from considering a role at your company again in future).

---

If they only applied and you haven't interacted with them at all yet, they may expect feedback to take a bit longer, but the 2-month threshold still roughly applies. Although this is only about negative feedback. If you want to invite them for an interview, this can happen much later. Consider that it's not too rare for companies to keep candidate information on file to potentially reach out to them about future opportunities, and companies often even reach out to people who've *never* applied.

---

Of course the better guiding principle here is that you should, in general, **let them know as soon as you've made a decision**.

You should let them know as soon as you've decided they won't proceed to the next round or won't get an offer.

If it takes you, say, 4 months to make a decision about one particular candidate after a particular interview, that would be quite long and you should work to decrease that, but it would be more reasonable to let a candidate know after such a long time if that's just how long you took to make the decision. Ideally you would at least **let candidates know how long you'll take to make a decision** (roughly speaking). This is helpful information whether it takes 4 months or 4 hours to get feedback.

Comment: "Between 1 week and 1 month is slow" - I cant remember the last time I have interviewed for a position or have interviewed applicants for a position where the time it took to interview to first person to the last was less than several weeks.

Comment: @Keltari Edited slightly.

Comment: @Keltari Even then, there's no reason not to explain "We still have several candidates to interview, and we'll be making our selection week-ending X."

Comment: I am guessing this answer is making assumptions and generalisation from a particular field or country. Personally I have never received an answer in less than one week after an interview, be it for acceptance or rejection. And when I applied by email and haven't been interviewed yet, more often than not I had to wait for weeks or months for an answer (usually I would send reminders email every other week if I'm still interested).

Comment: These are for internship positions. In university, I received interview offers more than 3 months after applying and to this day I don't think I've ever gotten a response within a week, even for companies that hired me

Comment: @Mars This answer only applies to letting candidates know about rejection after an interview. The time between applying and interviewing can be completely different.

Comment: Ah, I missed the "from interview" part, since the OP's question is for people who were not interviewed. There's also a huge difference between "from interview" and "from last contact"

Comment: Funny how a lot of things boil down to the famous _'6-8 weeks'_..

Answer (score 15):

As it has already been pointed out, the right thing to do would have been to notify the applicants many months ago. However that ship has sailed.

Having been many times on the receiving end of rejections to my applications, I would always rather have a negative answer many months later than no answer at all. Furthermore, if I don't receive an answer at all, I assume that the company has little regard for the people it interacts with, which makes me think twice about wanting to work with them.

Send a message to the rejected candidates, underline the unexpectedly high number of applicants, and next time do better.

Comment: This. OP's company messed up (that's OK, sh*t happens, and Covid made this an especially difficult year), and if you mess up, the professional thing to do is to (a) fix your mistake and (b) apologize. And that's exactly what should be done here: A polite rejection including a sincere apology for the late reply. Not because it's a (final) chance to turn a bad impression into a good one, but because it's simply the right thing to do.

Comment: @Heinzi - Covid had nothing to do with the company NOT notifying somebody by email or a phone call.  It takes no effort to write a single response to be emailed to each individual.

Comment: This is the best answer. I'm shocked, but I suppose not surprised, that the top answers actually recommend ghosting the applicants en masse, which is incredibly unprofessional.

Answer (score 3):

With a qualified explanation.

Hiring processes can take a great many months. It would have been nice to tell applicants that they had not been shortlisted. Too late now but you could have explicitly stated that only shortlisted applicants will be contacted.

This is nowhere near as bad as making an offer and then ghosting the successful applicant.

But a paragraph explaining the protracted hiring process and your appreciation of their effort may go a long way. I have been hired at least once after 6 months of silence and no interview at all.

Answer (score 2):

What about sending a message that you regret not replying / replying late and that you and the company will do better in the future? I'm not in HR, however I think it's a good moment to own up to mistakes and to learn from them. The gain from sending them a message this late is that you might change the way your company is percieved among those candates.

Comment: Have you ever been in this situation, or seen it close, on any side of it? How did this approach work out?

Comment: @hyde On a much smaller scale, we missed a job application in a shared mailbox. However I answer more out of a personal belief that it's best to act when realizing you wronged someone. Worst case they don't accept the apology, best case they understand and are glad you're willing to change this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

From personal experience it's very common to be ghosted by companies if you don't get selected for an interview. It's not great, but to be expected at this point. I'm honestly surprised by all the people here that are saying they would blacklist a company that doesn't respond. In some fields that might be worthwhile (especially those with high demand), but in others (especially those with a lot of supply (of workers)) it's to be expected. When I applied earlier this year, 9 out of 10 companies where I didn't get an interview never responded.

I would advise not to ghost applicants in the future, but honestly, if I were to receive a rejection 9 months after applying, I would seriously wonder what's wrong with your company and you would definitely end up on my blacklist.

Chances are that most applicants have long since forgotten about it. Some might have blacklisted you for not replying, but honestly, you're not going to get of that blacklist by replying now (if anything you'll end up on more).

If you really want to send a reply still, send an apology instead of a rejection.

Answer (score 1):

It is OK to contact these applicants in one specific situation: if you would have a new position, you re-read their resumes, and have determined that they do qualify for the new position.

In that case, you can contact them with potentially good news - the company is now willing to invite them to an interview. But don't assume they will be happy - some people will have lost interest, or found other jobs, or just don't want to deal with you.

However, since in this specific case you are not planning to call them in for an interview, don't send a message.

EU note: under the GDPR you shouldn't even have that list. Only HR should keep the list, with consent from the applicants. By default you can only use the applicants details for the position being applied to; keeping it longer requires separate consent that must be **freely** given. Given the unequal position of the applicant, opt-out and similar dark patterns are obviously illegal.

Comment: Good point about the EU. Now I wonder how long you can even keep the list. By the time the position is filled, you don't need that list anymore, so shouldn't you get rid of it at that point?

Comment: @Dnomyar96: Until the position is filled, you can keep the list because it's necessary to handle the application process. After that, you can keep names on the basis of individual, freely given consent.

Comment: @Dnomyar96: It's not so simple: You can keep data without consent under GDPR if you have a legitimate interest, for example, defending against a potential discrimination lawsuit (in that example, how long you can keep it would depend on the statutory period of limitation). If in doubt, ask your lawyer and/or your data protection officer.